# Fetching rows from excel spreadsheet in HTML & JavaScript based on a key

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have used the following source (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/244583/Excel-to-HTML-table-conversion-and-code-generation) to make a form to fetch data from an excel sheet to an HTML table and it works perfectly(credits to Niral Soni).

Now I have to fetch specific rows based on a key (empid) which I am unable to do.
[image]

So what I have done til now is inserting an if statement before the inner loop to check for an id but only able to get the first value.

```
for(i = rs, r = 0,k=cs; i <= re; i++,r++,k++) {
                row = tbl.insertRow(r);
                row.className = (i == rs) ? 'tblHeader' : (i % 2 == 0) ? 'evenRow' : 'oddRow';
                for(j = cs, c = 0; j <= ce; j++,c++) {
                    // I have 106 as a hardcoded id which I will change later based on the user input.

                    if (Number(es.Cells(i,j).value)==106) {
                    col = row.insertCell(c);
                    col.className = (j == ce) ? 'lastCol' : '';
                    col.innerHTML = es.Cells(i,j).value || ' ';
                }

                }
            }
```

But it only gives the 1st value as follows.
[image]

So can someone help me figure out what am i doing wrong in this, or any other sources or codes I can refer.
Thanks.